# Mysql Connection For every application I am trying to run the same Error code

Tags: mysql, eclipse

```
    2016-05-17 11:15:02,420 WARN  localhost-startStop-1 JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (null,  message from server: "Host 'MyComputerName' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
```

I am running my application on my Computer only but it is showing the error.No permission problem also as I am trying on my system only,password,connection-url all correct .So What is the Problem ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error pretty much says it all:

> Host 'MyComputerName' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Your computer is able to connect to the MySQL server, but not allowed to connect to it using the credentials you specified. Make sure your host is allowed to connect to the server under the given user. You probably still need to add your host to the user, like:

```
GRANT ALL ON `database`.* TO 'user'@'MyComputerName';
```

Where `database` is the database you're trying to read and `user` is the actual username you're using to connect to the server.

Comment: The Server is on my System only so no remote connection and the above command i have used also but still  showing error